# How to iterate over a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an matrix

```
              X = [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
                  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
                  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
                   ...
                  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

and I want to iterate over the rows.

My goal is to implement the below for loop:

```
loglike = []
for i in X_test:
    p = np.sum(np.multiply(X[i], np.log(posprob)) + np.multiply((1-X[i]), np.log(1-posprob)))
    loglike.append(p)
print(loglike)
```

but I receive the error IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type.

Even when I try to do a simple for loop print statement I receive the same error.

```
for i in X:
     print(X[i])
```

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type.

I see other people have asked other people have asked this question, but the answer seem to be exactly what I have. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I would suggest printing `i` and seeing what it really is.

Comment: Do **not** iterate, just apply your transform on the whole array as a vector function

Comment: Use `range` (or `arange`) if you want to generate indices: `for i in range(x.shape[0]): x[i]...`.   Python also has a convenient `enumerate`.  This issue is just as true for lists as arrays.  `numpy` is python, so don't skip the Python basics.

Comment: Your followup question ignored all these comments and answers :(

Answer (score 1):

As a addition to @Eshwar S R's answer, this calculation can be done without a loop.

Is the output of the following code what you want?

```
loglike = np.sum(np.multiply(X_test, np.log(posprob)) + np.multiply((1-X_test), np.log(1-posprob)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

i is already a numpy array. No need to index it again as X[i]. Try this:

```
loglike = []
for i in X_test:
    p = np.sum(np.multiply(i, np.log(posprob)) + np.multiply((1-i), np.log(1-posprob)))
    loglike.append(p)
print(loglike)
```