# How to iterate over a numpy matrix based on a condition of another nump array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix X, and the labels to each vector of that matrix as a np array Y. If the value of Y is +1 I want to multiply the vector of matrix X by another vector W. If the value of Y is -1 I want to multiply the vector of matrix X by another vector Z.

I tried the following loop:

```
for i in X:
    if Y[i] == 1:
        np.sum(np.multiply(i, np.log(w)) + np.multiply((1-i), np.log(1-w)))
    elif Y[i] == -1:
        np.sum(np.multiply(i, np.log(z)) + np.multiply((1-i), np.log(1-z)))
```

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

i is the index of X, but I'm not sure how to align the index of X to the value in that index of Y.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please, when iterating make sure you **know** what `i` is.  If you don't have enough experience, add a `print(i)`.  Here `i` is an element of `X`, **not** an index.  Don't forget, `numpy` is python, and the basic Python iteration rules apply.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `np.where`, it is exactly what you need:

```py
res = np.where(Y == +1, np.dot(X, W), np.dot(X, Z))
```

This assumes that Y can take only value `+1` and `-1`. If that's not the case you can adapt the script above but we need to know what do you expect as result when Y takes a different value.

---

Also, try to avoid explicit for loops when using numpy, the resulting code will be thousands of times faster.

Answer (score 0):

While it is better to use a no-iteration approach, I think you need a refresher on basic Python iteration.

Make an array:

```
In [57]: x = np.array(['one','two','three'])
```

Your style of iteration:

```
In [58]: for i in x: print(i)
one
two
three
```

to iterate on indices use `range` (or `arange`):

```
In [59]: for i in range(x.shape[0]): print(i,x[i])
0 one
1 two
2 three
```

`enumerate` is a handy way of getting both indices and values:

```
In [60]: for i,v in enumerate(x): print(i,v)
0 one
1 two
2 three
```

Your previous question had the same problem (and correction):

[How to iterate over a numpy matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69338556/how-to-iterate-over-a-numpy-matrix)